Grafana Link 2 Panels on Same Dashboard When Clicking on a Table Row
I have 2 panels in a Grafana dashboard each containing a Table.
The first panel summarizes API errors by API name so looks like this:
Error Count   API Name 
203               API1
149               API2
100               API3
23                API4

The second panel display details about all API errors.
I want to be able to click on a row in the first panel, say on API2, and update the display in the second panel to only display API2 errors.
I have a variable named APIName which I have attempted to use in a data link, but it does want to work.
Both panels results are created by a Druid SQL source.
I try to use the APIName variable in the WHERE statement in the second panel but nothing happens.
Also, if I set a data link in the first panel, both the Error Count and the API Name values become links. Can this be confined just to the API Name?
Is a data link the way to go and if so, how do I use it? I tried assigning APIName=${__value.text} and the URL shows this when you hover over it, but this does nothing.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

You are asking several questions in one post but I will try to answer what I know.

Yes I think that data links would be a good solution for this.
Start by adding a variable (of type query) that lists all the api types. Let's call this variable 'APIName'.
Make the second panel filtered by this variable. I am not familiar with Druid, but in ANSI SQL it would be something like SELECT details FROM error_details WHERE api_name = ${APIName}
Once you have a filter working for this one save the filtered URL somewhere for reference.
Go back to the variable and make it hidden (change the variable's Show on Dashboard settings to Hidden)
Edit the first panel and add a data link that points to the a URL that looks like https://HOSTNAME/d/UUID/DASHBOARD?orgId=ORGID&var-APIName=${__data.fields.name}&${__url_time_range}. Replace HOSTNAME, UUID, DASHBOARD, ORGID with the values saved in step 4.

Note that the URL name of the variable is var-APIName.
As for the question if you can only set the link on one cell and not the entire row: yes, you can do it by adding an override to that cell and adding a data link to the override, see image below.

